# Java ME 8 on RPi. Error: 'detect_fb_type: unknown device type'

Tags: java

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 and I have installed Java ME 8 on it. I want to deploy, debug and profile programs on it remotely from NetBeans on my Windows laptop, and run them on my Pi but I am getting an error when I test the installation with the provided script `usertest.sh`. Instead of running Java ME properly, it starts with the message

`Java is starting. Press Ctrl-C to exit
detect_fb_type: unknown device type
[CRITICAL] [PROXY] iso=-1:Can't create server
can not connect to device manager
[ERROR] [AMS] iso=0:The MIDlet suite could not be run`

it then hangs and won't run ME, so I can't run Java ME programs on it.
Has anyone seen this problem and know of a solution?

Comment: Isn't JDK already pre-installed with raspbian ?

Comment: As far as I know that's Java SE. Java Micro Edition needs to be installed separately, but correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the (obvious) solution. Installing Java ME 8 Embedded causes the process `runMidlet` to run at startup. Killing the process and running `./usertest.sh` in the Java ME 8 `bin` directory, allows Java ME to start without any problems. I managed to run programs remotely from NetBeans from my laptop, so my Raspberry Pi is a useful development environment.